# Why shear stress is developed only in the two set of planes for a rotating pressurized solid cylinder? Why not in the third set of plane?

Tags: stress-strain, solid-mechanics

In case of a rotating pressurized solid cylinder,why shear stress is not developed in the $ABCD\  \& \ EFGH$ planes while the other two set of planes are having shear stress component?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the cross section in the frame of the rotating cylinder. (We'll need to add a centrifugal force in that frame to accommodate the outward inertial load that arises from rotation.) Let's assume that the shear stress is positive in the following directions:

[image]

Due to axisymmetry, if I rotate the system by 180° around the z-axis, the cross section looks identical, with the following positive shear directions:

[image]

But if I look at the back side of the cross section, the cross section also looks identical, with the following positive shear directions:

[image]

The only way to reconcile both views is if no shear stress existed on those planes in the first place.